# How to turn off or specify the nginx error log location?

Tags: nginx

I compiled the nginx on Ubuntu myself.
I start my nginx with -c nginx.conf parameter.
In my nginx.conf file, I try to turn off error log with but failed.

```
error_log /dev/null crit;
```

Still got the error message:
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/usr/nginx/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)

How could I turn off this log or change its location?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `error_log` declaration (your line)? :)

Comment: I tried just now, only use access_log, but still got the error message.
I didn't create the folder:/home/dist/carrier/nginx/logs.
Restarting nginx: nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/home/dist/carrier/nginx/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The syntax for disabling the error log is ok, but the [docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#error_log) state that a default logfile is used before the config is read. (which seems reasonable because how would it otherwise tell you you have an error in your config)

Try creating this file by hand with the correct permissions for the user that runs nginx. Or try starting the server as root.

Comment: That's what I have done. use --prefix when compiling nginx to set the correct logs location and create the folder when installing my nginx service.

Comment: `$ sudo chmod a+w /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/error.log` should help, but compiling nginx from source seems more viable solution.

Comment: Still unable to access it. I `chown`'d to `www-data:www-data` but that didn't help, either. Which user and group should the files belong to?

Comment: The `chmod a+w` is a bad idea in almost all cases. Ensure that `error_log` is set at the *top level* of the nginx configuration (even outside the `http` block log). You will still get `nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/usr/nginx/logs/error.log"`, but `[alert]` is not a critical error and your server will start up anyway. Tried with nginx 1.4.

Answer (score 17):

I solved this issue using the -p parameter when starting nginx e.g:

```
/home/ubuntu/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /home/ubuntu/nginx/conf/nginx.conf -p /home/ubuntu/nginx
```

This will prepend any log paths specified in the config with the prefix directory.

Comment: Prefix solution works for me :) I've changed prefix directory to one that has write permission!
Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to set `-p` to get it to work. But ensure that `error_log` is set at the *top level* of the nginx configuration. You will still get `nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/usr/nginx/logs/error.log"`, but `[alert]` is not a critical error and your server will start up anyway. Tried with nginx 1.4.

Comment: Looks like `-p` option doesn't fully work in older versions; in 1.12.2. (Or, it's perhaps based on differences regarding @Randall's answer)  ------
 P.S.  @nh2: Perhaps `[alert]` is not critical, but it strikes me as bad practice to get into a habit of ignoring such things, and thus it would be ideal to have a way to not ever emit it.  (1.12.2, at least, does that.)

Comment: @lindes Oh yes sure. A clean solution is better. The less `[alert]` you have appear, the less you have to read to debug stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this by using this configure parameter:

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/nginx" --error-log-path=/dev/stderr
```

Since I never use this nginx as a daemon and always run it in a shell, it makes sense for it to log errors to stderr.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve the problem by specifying a `-p` prefix; because that would only apply to the directives in the configuration file; and as RickyA already noted the problem is that there is a compiled-in error log that nginx wants to open even before it opens the configuration.  Changing permissions of the compiled-in error log is not ideal, for obvious reasons.

A workaround is to specify the error log as a configuration on the command line:

```
$ nginx -p . -g 'error_log error.log;'
```

or

```
$ nginx -p . -g 'error_log stderr;'
```

You'll still get an [alert] but at least it allowed me to start nginx as non-root on Ubuntu.

Comment: This also works/is necessary to properly run `nginx -t` as non-root (without recompiling). Without doing something like `nginx -t -g 'error_log stderr;'` the test will always fail without root.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this post on the nginx.org mailing list](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2009-June/013326.html) (extract quoted below), the `%%ERROR_LOG_PATH%%` is set as a compile option, and checked immediately on startup, causing the "Could not open" alert.  Specifying the prefix (with `-p`) may help suppress the alert, but *only* if the `%%ERROR_LOG_PATH%%` was specified as a **relative** path at compile time.

You can check how it is specified in your current executable with

`nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -oE 'error-log-path=\S*'`

That is why the solution proposed by @Michael works for some, but not for others.

> See changelog:
>
> Changes with nginx 0.7.53
>
> ...
>
> *) Change: now a log set by --error-log-path is created from the very 
>          start-up.
>
> *) Feature: now the start up errors and warnings are outputted to an 
>          error_log and stderr.
>
> ...
>
> Now compiled in error_log value always used to log errors at start 
>   time (and emits warning if nginx can't open it).  Once config file 
>   have been read - error_log from config will be used instead.
>
> If you have compiled nginx with error_log path relative to prefix 
>   - it should be possible to override startup error_log via -p 
>   switch.
>
> Maxim Dounin

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to use a command line parameter. Simply ensure you add the error_log directive to the very top of nginx.conf or at least before any error messages may occur.

nh2's comment from Jan 2016 suggests that this option would have been available for at least a couple years now. I can confirm it works and it's less hassle. Customisation to nginx.conf is less likely to cause issues with updates to a packaged nginx installation than the alternatives.