# nginx tries to open default error.log regardless of config

Tags: linux, nginx

I have a `~/nginx.conf` with `error_log /home/user/error.log` (also in http section), and it works smoothly with `sudo nginx -c ~/nginx.conf`.

But without `sudo` I get `[alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)`, though nginx seems to work.

What is the cause and how to get rid of it?

UPD:
used config

```
worker_processes 4;
pid /home/user/nginx.pid;

error_log /home/user/error.log;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log /home/user/access.log;
  error_log /home/user/httperror.log;

  server {
    listen 8080 default_server;

    root /home/user/static;
    index index.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That simply means you have no access rights to access the log file. Run `ls -l /var/log/nginx/error.log` to see who is the owner of that file and what are permission. You can change permission with `sudo chmod` and ownership with `sudo chown`. Permissions of the directory holding that file are also important

Comment: We can't answer without seeing your config.

Comment: @vrs, I understand that, but I don't know why nginx accesses default error.log, though it was changed in config

Comment: @timzh update you quiestion with the entire config, please

Comment: Does `nginx -c ~/nginx.conf -g "error_log /home/user/error.log;"` help?

Comment: BTW, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371925/how-to-turn-off-or-specify-the-nginx-error-log-location

Comment: @Curious, no; thanks for the link, now it at least makes sense