# How do I configure nginx to put its error.log file somewhere I have write privileges?

Tags: nginx

I assume I simply have to insert an entry into an `nginx.conf` file to resolve the error that is plaguing me (see below), but so far I haven’t had any luck figuring out the syntax.  Any help would be appreciated.

I want to run nginx as a regular user while having installed it using homebrew as a user with administrative privileges.  nginx is trying to write to the `error.log` file at `/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log`, which it cannot because my regular user lacks write privilege there.

Another wrinkle is coming from the fact that there are two `nginx.conf` files, a global and a local, and as far as I can tell they are both being read.  They are in the default homebrew location  `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and my local project directory `$BASE_DIR/nginx.conf`.

Here is the error that is generated as nginx attempts to start up:

```
[WARN] No ENV file found
10:08:18 PM web.1 |  DOCUMENT_ROOT changed to 'public/'
10:08:18 PM web.1 |  Using Nginx server-level configuration include 'nginx.conf'
10:08:18 PM web.1 |  4 processes at 128MB memory limit.
10:08:18 PM web.1 |  Starting php-fpm...
10:08:20 PM web.1 |  Starting nginx...
10:08:20 PM web.1 |  Application ready for connections on port 5000.
10:08:20 PM web.1 |  nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
10:08:20 PM web.1 |  2017/03/04 22:08:20 [emerg] 19557#0: "http" directive is duplicate in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
10:08:20 PM web.1 |  Process exited unexpectedly: nginx
10:08:20 PM web.1 |  Going down, terminating child processes...
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
10:08:20 PM web.1 Exited with exit code 1
```

Any help figuring out how to get nginx up and running so I can back to the development side of this project will be much appreciated.

Comment: I've found a partial solution to my own problem (and it's so obvious that I'm embarrassed with myself).  If I give myself write permission on the log files then that gets rid of the first error.  I.e. run  `sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/var/log/nginx/*.log` as administrative user.

Comment: Thanks to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371925/how-to-turn-off-or-specify-the-nginx-error-log-location?rq=1) for reminding me of that possibility.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx: Permission denied for nginx on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714902/nginx-permission-denied-for-nginx-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The whole problem stems from trying to run nginx as my ordinary user self despite the fact that nginx was installed by my user self with administrative privileges.  I was able to resolve both the errors shown here with the following commands executed as a user with administrative privileges:

```
sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/var/log/nginx/*.log
sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/var
sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/var/run
```

Note that the `/usr/local/var` directory appears to have been created by homebrew upon installing nginx and this machine is my laptop so I can’t see any reason not to open it up.  You might have greater security concerns in other scenarios.

I admit that when I wrote this question I thought it was about moving the `error.log` file to another directory.  Now I see that that is not a full solution, so instead the solution I present here is about giving ordinary users write privileges in the necessary directories.

The reason I changed my mind is that nginx can (and in this case does) generate errors *before* (or *while*) reading the `nginx.conf` files and needs to be able to report those errors to a log file.  Modifying the `nginx.conf` file was never going to solve my problem.  What woke me up to this issue was reading this post:  [How to turn off or specify the nginx error log location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371925/how-to-turn-off-or-specify-the-nginx-error-log-location?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to set the log path to a custom location by editing `nginx.conf`?

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

Change path to somewhere use has write privileges.

Comment: Which nginx.conf file should I edit?  Does the local one take precidence?

Comment: @Keith Im not sure about it, but project level conf should take precedence, you can easily test it out.

Comment: No luck.  I tried adding `access_log /Users/keith/Documents/AgEnt/everyone/logs/access.log;
error_log /Users/keith/Documents/AgEnt/everyone/logs/error.log;` to the top of my local `nginx.conf` file and it had no impact on the error message at all.  It doesn't appear that those lines are changing the location of the error.log file at all.